# Array values not being updated after foreach()

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have some associative arrays that store lexical data for a dictionary. Here is an example of the structure from an array called `$rowArray`:

```
    [2] => Array
        (
            [\lx] => gunu
            [\np] => LH
            [\ps] => noun
            [\ge] => thick grass in the field, thicket
            [\gn] => tshutlha
            [\lt] => 
            [\va] => 
            [\cf] => 
            [\ce] => 
            [\nt] => 
            [\oi] => gunu [LH] thick grass in the field, thicket (noun) (Sets. tshutlha)
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [\lx] => guru
            [\np] => S
            [\ps] => noun
            [\ge] => ankle
            [\gn] => lenyenyana
            [\xv0] => ʔam guru-ŋǀı̃ 
            [\xe0] => my ankles
            [\lt] => 
            [\va] => 
            [\cf] => 
            [\ce] => 
            [\nt] => 
            [\oi] => guru [S] ankle (noun) (Sets. lenyenyana) (ex. ʔam guru-ŋǀı̃ ‘my ankles’)
        )
```

I am creating a spreadsheet and I need to create a row of headings equivalent to the keys in the array above (e.g. headings would be \lx \np \ps ...) I am storing these values in a separate array called `$headArray`.

The problem is that some arrays have more values than others, so when I create my spreadsheet, the columns are misaligned. For instance, in `[2]` above, there are 11 values, but in `[3]` above, there are 13 values. So in the spreadsheet, the columns would not match exactly.

Therefore, I am first iterating through ALL of the keys of `$rowArray` to populate `$headArray` (that way it will always have the max # of headings possible):

```
$headArray = array(); 
            foreach($rowArray as $j=>$rA){
                foreach($rA as $r=>$a){
                    if(!in_array($r, $headArray)){ 
                        $pos = array_search($r, array_keys($rA)); 
                        array_splice($headArray, $pos, 0, $r);  
                    }

                }
            }
```

The output of this code is an array with all the possible headings in the correct order:

```
Array
(
    [0] => \lx
    [1] => \np
    [2] => \ps
    [3] => \ge
    [4] => \gn
    [5] => \xv0
    [6] => \xe0
    [7] => \xv1
    [8] => \xe1
    [9] => \lt
    [10] => \va
    [11] => \cf
    [12] => \ce
    [13] => \nt
    [14] => \oi
)
```

And then I use this list (`$headArray`) to iterate through all of the entries in `$rowArray` -- if an entry in `$rowArray` is missing a key that `$headArray` has, then I splice it in and make it blank. In effect, I am creating blank columns in my spreadsheet so everything aligns no matter what. To do this iteration, I use this code:

```
foreach($rowArray as $j=>$rA){
                if(count($rA) < count($headArray)){
                    $rA_keys = array_keys($rA); 
                    $rA_diff = array_diff($headArray, $rA_keys);  
                    foreach($rA_diff as $di=>$ff){ 
                        if(!array_key_exists($ff, $rA)){
                            $rA = array_slice($rA, 0, $di, true) + array($ff => '') + array_slice($rA, $di, NULL, true);    
                        } 
                    }
                } 

            }
```

The output of this code is as follows (compare to the first array in this post):

```
 Array
    (
        [\lx] => gunu
        [\np] => LH
        [\ps] => noun
        [\ge] => thick grass in the field, thicket
        [\gn] => tshutlha
        [\xv0] => 
        [\xe0] => 
        [\xv1] => 
        [\xe1] => 
        [\lt] => 
        [\va] => 
        [\cf] => 
        [\ce] => 
        [\nt] => 
        [\oi] => gunu [LH] thick grass in the field, thicket (noun) (Sets. tshutlha)
    )
Array
(
    [\lx] => guru
    [\np] => S
    [\ps] => noun
    [\ge] => ankle
    [\gn] => lenyenyana
    [\xv0] => ʔam guru-ŋǀı̃ 
    [\xe0] => my ankles
    [\xv1] => 
    [\xe1] => 
    [\lt] => 
    [\va] => 
    [\cf] => 
    [\ce] => 
    [\nt] => 
    [\oi] => guru [S] ankle (noun) (Sets. lenyenyana) (ex. ʔam guru-ŋǀı̃ ‘my ankles’)
)
```

It works, I think! So, with all of this background knowledge in mind, my questions are:

**1. Outside of these `foreach` loops, even though the results `print()` correctly, the arrays are not updated. Like, when I try to write the arrays to my spreadsheet, the updated values with the splicing and all of that stuff is NOT being saved. So how can I make it so that the arrays get updated in my `foreach` loops?**

**2. Is there a logically more efficient or better way of doing what I'm doing? This task has been giving me a headache for 4 days now and I'm not sure my method is the best!**

Comment: ^^ That is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [PHPexcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) library. I think you shouldn't be doing it like that to modify the arrays and to get the header based on the maximum of arrays. I would do it like this:

1. Find the correct header how you want it to be.
2. Before entering the data in excel by the special functions of the library which take the row  and column of the excel file, create a temporary array iterating the values from your arrays. If some header values are not found leave them blank.
3. After creating that temporary array which corresponds with your header, insert those values in the excel file.

Comment: I am using that library to do it, but I am inserting entire rows at a time using this method: `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray()` but I think doing it your way would require me to start all the way from the beginning, which I don't have time to do.

Comment: I think using setCellValue() is easier and safer, you can find doc how to use here:  https://gist.github.com/r-sal/4313500